# intersection of 2 linked list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

As many people know the above-mentioned problem is pretty classic in linked lists. I have been trying to solve that problem in leetcode using the hashing method(knowing another more optimal solution) but it is not passing all the testcases(41/46). I don't know which case I am not covering. any help is appreciated.

```
    def getIntersectionNode(self, headA: ListNode, headB: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    s = set()
    list1 = headA
    list2 = headB
    while (not list1) or (not list2):
        return None
    
    while list1 and list1.next:
        s.add(list1)
        list1 = list1.next
        
        
    while list2 and list2.next:
        if list2 in s:
            return list2
        list2 = list2.next
        
    return None
```

Comment: Please include a tag which indicates the language; it might increase visibility among people who are into the specific language.

Comment: *"any help is appreciated"*: maybe you should then check regularly to see where your input is needed. And comment on the answer that has been given.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `while list1 and list1.next:` to  `while list1:` and `while list2 and list2.next:` to `while list2:`.

Example that doesn't work in your case:

> List 1: 1->5
>
> List 2: 2->5

In your code, for list 1, 1 will be inserted in set but not 5. In list 2, 2 will be checked in set but not 5.

Also, this should fail.

> List 1: 1->5
>
> List 2: 5

Like this you can get other failing test cases.

Answer (score 0):

We can also solve this problem just a bit more statementless:

```
class Solution:
    def getIntersectionNode(self, la, lb):
        if not la or not lb:
            return 
        a, b = la, lb
        while a and b and a != b:
            a, b = a.next, b.next
            if a == b:
                return b
            if not a:
                a = lb
            if not b:
                b = la
        return a
```